Is there a kind of Hopital's rule for multivariable calculus?
Question: Is there a kind of Hopital's rule for multivariable calculus?
It is widely known that Hopital's rule can be applied for single-variable functions also multivariable functions when one reduces the variable. For example,
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y + \sin(y)}{y} = \lim\limits_{(x) \to (0)}x^2 + \lim\limits_{(y) \to (0)} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}=1 $$
So, converting a multivariable limit to a single-variable limit provides us to use the rules we have for single-variable limit i.e., Hopital's rule  is allowed.
Do we have such a theorem or rule to take limit easily for multivariable functions?

The problem is if you try$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{g(h)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\cdot\nabla f}{h\cdot\nabla g}$$you can't cancel the $h\cdot$s. Even if you could, you'd need a ratio of vectors to make sense.

@J.G.: There are some versions of L'Hopital's rule for several variables -- see this MSE answer AND Lawlor (2020). However, my guess is that none of these qualify as "to take limit easily" for the OP's purposes.

Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDZVhwjn_7g&ab_channel=Dr.Powell%27sMathClasses
